# converting a random integer to a string

Tags: python

I'm struggling to understand how I would change this code. Instead of converting the input value to an integer before comparing it to the random integer, I want to convert the random integer to a string and then do the comparison (comparing the string to a string). I am a beginner in programming. Also, I don't want the answer I'm asking, just how to understand it better and where I should start. I apologize that this might seem easy to people, but I'm struggling with it.

```
import random
#this function generates a random number between 1 and 100 and asks the user to guess the      number
def playGame2():
    number = random.randint(1,100)
    guess = input("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.  Guess what it is: ")
    if number == int(guess):
        print("That is correct!")
    else:
        print("Nope...I was thinking of " + str(number))
```

Comment: The answer is already in your question: "I want to convert the random integer to a string". Just as you use `int` to convert to an integer, use `str` to convert to a string.

Comment: All i had to do on the 6th line of code is change "if number == str(guess):"?

Comment: @RyanErickson: Almost, but you want to cast the `number` to a string... `guess` is already a string.

Comment: it is saying the str is not defined if I do that

Answer (score 2):

As Mark Ransom said above, you've essentially already answered your own question; using `str` converts to a string, much like `int` converts to an integer.

To use this most effectively, you can convert your random integer to a string immediately after generation:

```
number = str(random.randint(1,100))
```

Now, since `number` and `guess` are both strings, there's no need to do any further casting in order to compare or print them.

Comment: Thank you for your guys help.  I'm a slow learner in programming, just still getting down the different between strings and ints.

Answer (score 1):

You're still having to deal with the fact that I can enter `eight` instead of `8`.  You're real close and everyone's help has gotten you there but try and use some exception handling here just in case, it's NEVER too early to start handling exceptions!

```
    def playGame2():
        number = str(random.randint(1,100))
        try:
            guess = input("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.  Guess what it is: ")
            if number == int(guess):
                print("That is correct!")
            else:
                print("Nope...I was thinking of " + str(number))
        except:
            print "Oops, please use a numeric value."
        playGame2()
```

This will get you through the NameError that you get if someone types out a word.  I know this is probably just for you or a class but it's still good practice.